# How to implement a sliding ImageView as a header on a Eureka form

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, eureka-forms

[I am unsure how to implement a sliding imageview like the one in the top of this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b45OG.jpg)

I am using Eureka forms and I'm trying to include this sliding imageview as a header.

At the moment I am using a custom view and this [Library](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow)

I think the root of my issue is caused by the gesture recognizer and the method "click". Xcode throws an error on the `self.presentViewController(ctr,animated: true,completion:nil)` line. I understand it can't present a viewcontroller inside a UIView. I'm just unsure of how I can achieve the same result of presenting the view controller inside the UIView sub class.

Here is my code:

```
class profilePicHeader: UIView {

let slideshow = ImageSlideshow()
var slideshowTransitioningDelegate: ZoomAnimatedTransitioningDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let localSource = [ImageSource(imageString: "GardenExample")!,ImageSource(imageString: "OvenExample")!]


    slideshow.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    slideshow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.UnderScrollView
    slideshow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    slideshow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill


    slideshow.setImageInputs(localSource)


    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(profilePicHeader.click))
    slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    slideshow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)
    slideshow.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130)
    slideshow.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    self.addSubview(slideshow)
}

func click() {
    let ctr = FullScreenSlideshowViewController()
    ctr.pageSelected = {(page: Int) in
        self.slideshow.setScrollViewPage(page, animated: false)
    }

    ctr.initialImageIndex = slideshow.scrollViewPage
    ctr.inputs = slideshow.images
    slideshowTransitioningDelegate = ZoomAnimatedTransitioningDelegate(slideshowView: slideshow, slideshowController: ctr)
    // Uncomment if you want disable the slide-to-dismiss feature on full screen preview
    // self.transitionDelegate?.slideToDismissEnabled = false
    ctr.transitioningDelegate = slideshowTransitioningDelegate
    self.presentViewController(ctr, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would be to use a container view and a page view controller. You add a container view and set auto layout constraints to size the container, then add all the images to a page view controller inside.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know we do not able present a UIViewController from UIView. So to resolve your problem you need add UIViewController's view in window and show proper animation.

To perform this task, we hav a good libary call MJPopupViewController. By using this you can present a UIViewController from UIView with different transition effects. Library: https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController

Let us know if you have any problem in integrate this library.

Thanks.